# Python make dictionary items accessible as object property

Tags: python

This is mostly syntactic sugar but I'd like to access the items of a dictionary as object properties.

Example:

```
class CoolThing():
  def __init__(self):
    self.CoolDict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

and I'd like to have

```
my_cool_thing.a # => 1
my_cool_thing.b # => 2
```

**Edit: some code of a potential solution with a nested structure with dot notation: device.property.field**

```
class Parameters():

    def __init__(self, ids, devices):
        self._ids = ids
        self._devices = devices
        for p in self._devices:
            p = p[0]
            if self.__dict__.get(p.device) is None:
                self.__dict__[p.device] = SmartDict()
            else:
                if self.__dict__[p.device].get(p.property) is None:
                    self.__dict__[p.device][p.property] = SmartDict()
                else:
                    if self.__dict__[p.device][p.property].get(p.field) is None:
                        self.__dict__[p.device][p.property][p.field] = ParameterData(p)

class SmartDict():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = {}

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.__dict__[k]

    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        self.__dict__[k] = v

    def get(self, k):
        return self.__dict__.get(k)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__dict__)
```

Comment: Look into [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__).

Comment: Thanks, `__getattr__` and `__dict__` are the things I was looking for. How does it interact with `@property`? While lookup for an attribute, `@property` goes before `__getattr__`?

Comment: @CedricH. I've expanded my answer to include that information.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini A property will be looked up before the instance `__dict__`. `__getattr__` is only used as a last resort when every  thing else has failed (property or other descriptor, instance dict, class and parents dicts).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: right, sorry

Comment: @CedricH. Reading your question again, you ask for the items of `CoolDict` to be available as `obj.attr`, but maybe on top of the other normal instance attributes. Can you please clarify if __all__ attributes must go into `CoolDict` or the object can also have attributes assigned in the normaly way, through `self.` and ending up in `self.__dict__` only?

Comment: @Pynchia I must admit I didn't think that far. I assumed my "dict" attributes wouldn't collide with normal attributes/methods of my objects. The goal was to have a nested structure of `dict` to allow nice `.` lookup (matlab style to please the users of my package) and iPython notebook completion. I updated the question to show the dirtiness of my solution based on Andrea's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) and [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__), though you'll have to roll your own class (I'm not aware of any builtins, though `namedtuple` might work if you don't need to change values much)

```
class AttrDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self[attr]

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self[attr] = value
```

If you just want to access a sub-dictionary that way, you just change `self` to `self.cool_dict`

```
class CoolThing:
   def __init__(self):
      self.cool_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

   def __getattr__(self, attr):
      return self.cool_dict[attr] 

   def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
      # Note, you'll have to do this for anything that you want to set
      # in __init__. 
      if attr == 'cool_dict':
          super().__setattr__(attr, value)
      else:
          self.cool_dict[attr] = value
```

Note that `__getattr__` is used *after* any other lookups fail, but if you want to ensure that your function is called first, you can use [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)

Also note that `self.cool_dict` does *not* exist on `CoolThing` until after `__init__` is called. My initial version of this would throw a maximum recursion depth exceeded, because as you created the class it would go to set `self.cool_dict` in init, call `__setattr__`, which would try to get `self.cool_dict` so it could set `[attr] = value` on it. Naturally it can't find `cool_dict` yet, and so it will try to call `__getattr__` again... which can't find `cool_dict` and round and round it goes.

Another option would be to use a class-level variable instead, but that's probably not at all what you want :)

Comment: Messing with `__getattribute__` is more often than not a false good idea. First because it can be tricky, but also because it will slow down attributes resolution by a noticeable factor (at least it was quite noticeable last time I benchmarked this solution).

Comment: have you tried your code? The solution does NOT work. Max recursion depth exceeded

Comment: @Pynchia ah, you're right when it comes to the `__getattr__` - that's because the `self.cool_dict` part. Trying to find a workaround.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That's good advice. Then again, it's probably wise to think a few times before mucking about with *any* of the dunder methods.

Answer (score 5):

`CoolDict` already exists, it's named `__dict__`:

```
>>> class CoolThing(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__dict__['a'] = 1
...         self.__dict__['b'] = 2
... 
>>> thing = CoolThing()
>>> thing.a
1
>>> thing.b
2
>>> thing.c = 3
>>> thing.__dict__
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: This will not provide the  `mapping` API  - except by direct access to the instance `__dict__` which is definitely not a great idea.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: but this is what the OP asked for :)

Comment: "I'd like to access the items of a dictionary as object properties" - this doesn't mean he's willing to give up on the mapping API ;)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: my aim was to let the user know about `__dict__`. I'm sorry but I'm not going to write anything more sophisticated than that

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm not sure I understand what you mean 'mapping API'

Comment: @CedricH.: the mapping API is the one exposed by dictionaries. He suggests that you should be able to use both `thing['a']` and `thing.a`

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Ok, got it. In that case your solution is all fine. My class would contain different things, among them a dictionary, which I'd move to `__dict__`.

Comment: @CedricH. if your class is supposed to be anythin else than a `dict` with added support for attribute notation access, you may want to be __sure__ you fully understand Python's object system (including full attributes resolution rules, the descriptor protocol, the relationships between instances, classes and metaclasses etc) before messing with implementation attributes like `__dict__`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm sure I don't but actually I'm looking at that and other aspects I'm not confortable with yet ;)